# populating datatable with Firebase and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am very new to Firebase and the whole web-development spiel.

I am trying to populate a datatable in my website with data from my Firebase.

[This is the datatable in bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd6yH.png)

Following is the app.js

```
var app = angular.module("aocgApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("dataController", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray", 
function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var national = new Firebase("https://aoconsultinggroup.firebaseio.com/National");
    $scope.schools = $firebaseArray(national);
}]);
```

and finally, the html code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div ng-app="aocgApp" ng-controller="dataController">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>School Name</th>
                <th>SATs</th>
                <th>GPA</th>
                <th>Tuition</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="school in schools">
                <td>{{ schools.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ schools.sat24l }}</td>
                <td>{{ schools.gpa }}</td>
                <td>{{ schools.tuition }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks for all your help.

EDIT: following is the data structure

```
 aoconsultinggroup
  L Business
  L CS
  L Engineering
  L National
    L 0
       L name
       L SAT
       L GPA
       L tuition
    L 1
       L name
       L SAT
       L GPA
       L tuition
    L 2
       L name
       L SAT
       L GPA
       L tuition
    L 3
       L name
       L SAT
       L GPA
       L tuition
```

Comment: There are at least two glaringly obvious typos here. Please perform due diligence before asking others to debug your code. `schools` inside the `$loaded` callback (which you don't need) should be $scope.schools, and the `ng-repeat` should refer to `school in schools`.

Comment: that was taken care of long before you commented. Sorry about that I forgot to fix it in the original post. Even after that though Kato, the datatable isn't being populated, what else would be the issue? I've been struggling with this for 2 days with no success or leads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong variable name in your template, it's `schools` not `national`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="school in schools">
  <td>{{ school.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ school.sat24l }}</td>
  <td>{{ school.gpa }}</td>
  <td>{{ school.tuition }}</td>
</tr>
```

In your controller, you don't need to use `$loaded()`. When the data has downloaded, the `$firebaseArray()` will trigger the `$digest` loop.

All you need is this:

```
var national = new Firebase("<your-firebase-app>/National");
$scope.schools = $firebaseArray(national);
```

That's what makes `school in schools` work in the template. The `schools` variable is from the controller's `$scope`, and the `school` variable is created in the template.

Comment: whoops, i was playing around with the variable name in the html. but thank you so much! i will try this out now and get back to the thread!

Comment: am i missing something? because it's still not working. I've had a function that I copied and pasted from Firebase tutorial to check for established connection with Firebase. And it doesn't have any problems connecting. I'm so lost...

Comment: Can you be clear about what's not working? Also, if you could post the structure of your database that would be helpful.

Comment: so the datatable isn't being populated at all. i will edit original post about the datastructure

Comment: Updated from your data structure.

Comment: `var app = angular.module("aocgApp", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("dataController", ["$scope", "$firebaseObject", 

 function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var national = new Firebase("https://aoconsultinggroup.firebaseio.com/National");
  $scope.school = $firebaseObject(national);
 }
]);`
This is the edited app.js but the table isn't being populated still... :(

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or JSBin to recreate the issue?

Comment: I just realized that I displayed the data structure incorrectly.
I have updated the visualization of the data structure, please see post

Comment: In that case my original answer should work as you need a list of schools.

Comment: I still can't use your JSFiddle, because it gives an error and the console. If you can fix that I'll take a look.

Comment: [here is the new jsf](https://jsfiddle.net/hyorkim11/t4g0hbrz/#&togetherjs=t4yN987HDw)
but i still don't get an error on my end

Comment: JSFiddle is having some errors, so I created a JSBIn with the same code. You can't see the data because of your security rules. So rather than use the same Firebase database, you can create a new one with sample data for the sake of this question. http://jsbin.com/lopodokomu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: each of the "school" entity is labeled as numbers from 0~99, do you think this is the problem? or does this have nothing to do with my problem?